# I have json data and i want to select some items only how can i do it in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing

```
   {
       "data": [
            {
                "category": "Organization", 
                "name": "GITM IEEE", 
                "category_list": [
                    {
                        "id": "198503866828628", 
                        "name": "Organization"
                    }
                ], 
                "access_token": "x", 
                "perms": [
                    "EDIT_PROFILE", 
                    "CREATE_CONTENT", 
                    "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
                    "CREATE_ADS", 
                    "BASIC_ADMIN"
                ], 
                "id": "474676675993584"
            }, 
            {
                "category": "Event planning/event services", 
                "name": "Ignitron 2014", 
                "category_list": [
                    {
                        "id": "192119584190796", 
                        "name": "Event"
                    }
                ], 
                "access_token": "x", 
                "perms": [
                    "ADMINISTER", 
                    "EDIT_PROFILE", 
                    "CREATE_CONTENT", 
                    "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
                    "CREATE_ADS", 
                    "BASIC_ADMIN"
                ], 
                "id": "731808386867764"
            }, 
            {
                "access_token": "x", 
                "category": "Community organization", 
                "perms": [
                    "ADMINISTER", 
                    "EDIT_PROFILE", 
                    "CREATE_CONTENT", 
                    "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
                    "CREATE_ADS", 
                    "BASIC_ADMIN"
                ], 
                "name": "GITM Model United Nations (GITM MUN)", 
                "id": "232082683584902"
            }, 
            {
                "access_token": "x", 
                "category": "Computers/technology", 
                "perms": [
                    "ADMINISTER", 
                    "EDIT_PROFILE", 
                    "CREATE_CONTENT", 
                    "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
                    "CREATE_ADS", 
                    "BASIC_ADMIN"
                ], 
                "name": "Bros!s", 
                "id": "332832946796051"
            }, 
            {
                "access_token": "x", 
                "category": "Musician/band", 
                "perms": [
                    "ADMINISTER", 
                    "EDIT_PROFILE", 
                    "CREATE_CONTENT", 
                    "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
                    "CREATE_ADS", 
                    "BASIC_ADMIN"
                ], 
                "name": "6 Strings", 
                "id": "267855836697950"
            }, 
            {
                "access_token": "x", 
                "category": "Sports team", 
                "perms": [
                    "ADMINISTER", 
                    "EDIT_PROFILE", 
                    "CREATE_CONTENT", 
                    "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
                    "CREATE_ADS", 
                    "BASIC_ADMIN"
                ], 
                "name": "Counter Strike::74th Cavalry", 
                "id": "486465148068957"
            }, 
            {
                "access_token": "x", 
                "category": "Entertainer", 
                "perms": [
                    "ADMINISTER", 
                    "EDIT_PROFILE", 
                    "CREATE_CONTENT", 
                    "MODERATE_CONTENT", 
                    "CREATE_ADS", 
                    "BASIC_ADMIN"
                ], 
                "name": "Bakchod's of Hostel.", 
                "id": "356188731080152"
            }
        ]
    }
```

this is the data and i want to select the name of the page how can i do it in python ?

Comment: I believe python has an in-built "json" module. You can use it to retrieve the value.

Link to json doc => https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: "the name of the page"? What page? What's the expected output? Is it `GITM IEEE`? Is it `Ignitron 2014`? Is it a list `['GITM IEEE', 'Ignitron 2014', ...]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the work:

```
import json

json_file = open('your_json_file_path')
json_dict = json.load(json_file)

site_names = []

for page in json_dict.get('data', []):
    if page.get('name'):
        site_names.append(page['name'])

print site_names
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[u'GITM IEEE', u'Ignitron 2014', u'GITM Model United Nations (GITM MUN)', u'Bros
!s', u'6 Strings', u'Counter Strike::74th Cavalry', u"Bakchod's of Hostel."]
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the lists of dicts in  `json_data["data"]` and access whatever you need using the key.

```
print([dic["name"] for dic in json_data["data"]])
['GITM IEEE', 'Ignitron 2014', 'GITM Model United Nations (GITM MUN)', 'Bros!s', '6 Strings', 'Counter Strike::74th Cavalry', "Bakchod's of Hostel."]
```

If there is a chance `name` is not in every dict use `in` to check:

```
print([dic["name"] for dic in d["data"] if "name" in dic])
```

Comment: Thanks alot for solving my problem.